# toggle checkboxes and hide content

Tags: jquery, checkbox, toggle

Could someone help me out with this simple function:

I have 2 checkboxes, one called "**other**" and the other "**info**"

When user clicks on "**other**" "**info**" needs to be disabled and some content hidden.
When "**info**" is checked, "**other**" needs to be enabled and additional content shown.

Here is the code:

```
  $("#mydiv").on("click", ".docheck :checkbox", function () {
      if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
          if ($(this).prop('name') == "other") {
              $(".header").toggle()
          } else {
              $(".header").toggle()
              $('.docheck').find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', false);
              $(this).prop('checked', true)
          }
      }
  });
```

So far it works partially. After few clicks, both checkboxes end up being checked.

Comment: If the checkboxes are alternatives can't you use a radio option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean checked/unchecked not enabled/disabled.

To solve with one function I:

1. save the current selection of the check
2. clear the situation
3. set the current selection/visibility according to the previous checked element

The code can be better, but for now:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#mydiv").on("click", ".docheck", function () {
        wasCheck = $(this).is(':checked');
        $('.docheck').prop('checked', false);
        $(".header, .info").hide();
        if (wasCheck) {
            if ($(this).prop('name') == "other") {
                $(".header").show()
            } else {
                $(".info").show()
            }
            $(this).prop('checked', true)
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TYhqZ/1

Comment: Thank you very much. Works perfect, just a minor change
$(".header").show() should be $(".header").hide()